# jquery: post with json will actually post array

Tags: python, json

I have a python as CGI and the POST from jquery will transform json object to array, so when I see the POST from jquery, I actually see:

```
login_user[username]=dfdsfdsf&login_user[password]=dsfsdf
```

(the [ and ] already escaped)

My question is how I can convert this string back to JSON in python? Or, how can I convert this string to python array/dict structure so that I can process it easier?

[edit]
My jquery is posting:

```
{'login_user': {'username':username, 'password':password}}
```

Comment: Your jQuery code looks like...?

Comment: How would regular expressions sound? We can try to design a pattern for this... although I can't stop requoting: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." ~ Jamie Zawinski, in comp.emacs.xemacs

Comment: @Soul: Why are you suggesting regexes then, if you already know they're a bad idea?? Python has a `simplejson` library for this... once you manage to get it into a dict.

Comment: @Soul: `&` strikes me as a perfectly legal password character... which is the problem. Regexes might work for most cases, but one tiny little thing like that, and they explode.

Comment: @Soul: Not to mention your regex solves a very specific use case... what if he changes his variable names? What if he wants to add more? What if the arrays are multi-dimensional? (see his other Q)... any little change, and you have to re-write your regex..it's just not practical unless it's a 1-off job.

Comment: @Mark, I totally agree. My answer is a 1-off job, I'm looking into the `simplejson` library right now, let's see where we can get.

Comment: @Mark, by the way `&` will not break the expression, `&login_user[password]=` will if that is contained after the `[username]=` then will the expression blow. Otherwise `&` will work, I've just tried it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you want to accomplish is to send structured data from the browser and then unpack it in your Python backend and keep the same structure, I suggest the following:

1. Create JavaScript objects in the browser to hold your data:

   ```
   var d = {} 
   d['login_user'] = { 'username': 'foo', 'password': 'bar' }
   ```
2. Serialize to JSON, with https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js
3. POST to your backend doing something like this:

   $.post(url, {'data': encoded_json_data}, ...)
4. In your Python code, parse the JSON, POST in my example is where you get your POST data in your CGI script:

   ```
   data = json.loads(POST['data'])
   data['login_user']
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

thestring = "login_user[username]=dfdsfdsf&login_user[password]=dafef"

pattern = re.compile(r'^login_user\[username\]=(.*)&login_user\[password\]=(.*)')
match = pattern.search(thestring)
print match.groups()
```

Output:
`>>> ('dfdsfdsf', 'dafef')`

Thus,

```
lp = match.groups()
print "{'login_user': {'username':"+lp[0]+", 'password':"+lp[1]+"}}"
```

shall bear: `>>> {'login_user': {'username':dfdsfdsf, 'password':dafef}}`

Comment: Wasn't me. But I'll +1 to bring you back up to 0

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {'login_user':{'username':'dfdsfdsf', 'password':'dsfsdf'}}
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"login_user": {"username": "dfdsfdsf", "password": "dsfsdf"}}'
```

I suspect that `data` would already be contained in a `GET` var if that's coming from the URL...